# Double Superscript could't build and view

Tags: math-mode

Have the problem with this

```
$u^{\prime}^2=(u^{\prime}_{peak}^2)\mathrm{e}^{-\dfrac{(x-x_{peak})}{l_{turb}}$.
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Double superscripts, in general, are ambiguous, and you have to group the code with braces to remove the ambiguity.  Also, you had a mismatched brace that needed correction. I left your `\mathrm{e}`, though generally, the italic `e` is preferred for the exponential.  Finally, subscripts that are words (`peak`) or abbreviations for words (`turb`) should be set in roman, rather than italic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
${u^{\prime}}^2=({u^{\prime}_\mathrm{peak}}^2)
  \mathrm{e}^{-\dfrac{(x-x_\mathrm{peak})}{l_\mathrm{turb}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For fractional exponents, you might consider the alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
${u^{\prime}}^2=({u^{\prime}_\mathrm{peak}}^2)
  \exp\biggl({-\dfrac{(x-x_\mathrm{peak})}{l_\mathrm{turb}}}\biggr)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would typeset it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}
\[
  {u'}^2 =\Bigl({u'_{\textup{peak}}}^2\Bigr) 
    e^{-\frac{(x-x_{\textup{peak}})}{l_{\textup{turb}}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

I.e. use of `'` instead of `\prime`, use of `\text`  instead of `\mathrm` so you are sure to match your text fonts, and with `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` delimiters around the first factor. `\bigl` and `\bigr` would do as well, but I find them a bit too small in this font.

**Edit** `\textup` is even better than `\text` in this case: it allows to stick to the upright version of the current font, whatever the environment.

[image]

Comment: The unaligned minus and fraction bar make me mad…

Comment: @Fatalize Agreed, it's ugly. It's a side-effect of the `\dfrac` command in inline formulas, as it is the case in the OP's subject. I've edited my answer: now it is in display mode. See Steven's answer for correct typesetting in inline mode (which I personnaly wouldn't use for such a formula).

Comment: Very bad use of the `\text` command, please don't promote this use, it does not do what you think.

Comment: @daleif May I ask you why?

Comment: `\text ` matches the surrounding text font, so if this is used in for example a theorem (which traditionally had italic text), the output from `\text` will be italic, and textual comments should **always** be upright, see egregs answer

Comment: This misuse of `\text` is sadly very common.

Comment: @daleif I never write in italics, that's probably the reason I never saw `\text` could be a problem. I suppose the `\textup` command would be better than `\text` then. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I personally use `\textup` one could also use `\textnormal`, these have the advantage over `\mathrm` that more letters are allowed (for example `R_{\textup{sø}} `for the radius of a Danish lake)

Answer (score 2):

The problems are in

```
u^{\prime}^2
```

and

```
u^{\prime}_{peak}^2
```

that indeed have two superscripts. You might do

```
{u'}^{2}
```

and

```
{u'_{\mathrm{peak}}}^2
```

but the second exponent would be hanging from nowhere. In my opinion there is nothing wrong in

```
u_{\mathrm{peak}}'^{\,2}
```

A display style fraction in the next exponent is also out of the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ec}{\mathrm{e}}% Euler's constant

\begin{document}

\noindent First attempt
\[
{u'}^2=({u^{\prime}_{peak}}^2)\mathrm{e}^{-\dfrac{(x-x_{peak})}{l_{turb}}}
\]
Second attempt
\[
u'^{\,2}=u_{\mathrm{peak}}'^{\,2} \, \ec^{-(x-x_{\mathrm{peak}})/l_{\mathrm{turb}}}
\]
Third attempt
\[
u'^{\,2}=u_{\mathrm{peak}}'^{\,2} \exp\bigl(-(x-x_{\mathrm{peak}})/l_{\mathrm{turb}}\bigr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second and third attempts may also be used in line instead of being displayed, although I feel that such a complex formula is better displayed.